# Is there any better way to create JSON array containing nested JSON?

Tags: sql, mysql, json, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this (in real it has more columns but they doesn't matter for the question)

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` longtext,
  `owner` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and a table for attachments (also shortened)

```
CREATE TABLE `attachments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answer_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longblob,
  `thumb` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `answer` (`answer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `answerid` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `answers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and a table for the users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `sso` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sso`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to get all answers in a JSON format like this:

```js
[{
    "id" : 1
    "text": "Whatever",
    "owner":
    {
       "sso" : "123456",
       "lastName" : "Miller"
    },
    "attachments":
    [
         {
             "id" : 1,
             "fileName" : "Image",
             "thumb" : "BASE64ENCODEDIMAGE"
         },
         {
             "id" : 2,
             "fileName" : "Image2",
             "thumb" : "BASE64ENCODEDIMAGE"
         },
    ]
}/*, ... */]
```

So my actual query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.text,
       CASE WHEN u.sso IS NOT NULL THEN JSON_OBJECT('sso', u.sso, 'lastName', u.name) END AS owner,
       CASE WHEN at.id IS NOT NULL THEN JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', at.id, 'fileName', at.file_name, 'thumb', TO_BASE64(at.thumb))) END AS attachments,
FROM answers
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.sso = a.owner
LEFT JOIN attachments at ON at.answer_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
WHERE ...
```

This works for me but I know, it's normally not allowed to group by only one selected column.
An alternative Approach would be to sub select the attachment, but wouldn't this cost much of performance (There could be many answers)?
So I am here to ask, if there is a complete different approach to reach my goal or any hints what you would do in this situation.

Comment: You want 1 JSON row per answer?

Comment: Yes that's the goal